# Validation effects the entire form, no button can be pressed

Tags: c#, .net, forms, validation

I've got a page that contains a huge amount of controls, (gridviews, reportviewers, buttons etc.)

Now I've a couple of textboxes and dropdowns that represent a "form" user might want to fill up and submit by clicking a button. Some of these controls contain "RequiredFieldValidator"s.

```
<fieldset runat="server" >
                    <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text="Name:" AssociatedControlID="txtName" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvTxtName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtName" Text="(Required)" />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" Width="175px" runat="server" />
                    ....
                    ....
 </fieldset>
```

The problem I encounter is that no other button on the entire asp form can be clicked because of these validation controls.

The question is; how do I set this validation to only listen to that particular fieldset and not the whole page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your controll's `ValidationGroup` property to make them one group . Like

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" 
            ValidationGroup="MyGroup" />
```

> The ValidationGroup property specifies which group of controls is
>   validated on validation. This property is mostly used when there are
>   several buttons in a form.

[ASP.NET ValidationGroup Property](http://www.w3schools.com/aspnet/prop_webcontrol_imagebutton_validationgroup.asp)

Comment: Works like a charm. I've read the whole chapter about Validation controls and completely forgot about the validationGroup. Me dumb! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 3):

Set the [ValidationGroup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basevalidator.validationgroup.aspx) property of those controls to something unique.

More info [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227424.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You ca also change property **CausesValidation** to **False** for control that you don't want to validate.